# Expected literal value at character - Json string

Tags: java, android, json

This is my Json string :

```
[{\DoctorId\:3,\UserId\:0,\FirstName\:\Nitish\,\MiddleName\:\\,\LastName\:\Rana
\,\Qualification\:null,\Description\:null,\Experience\:null,\Email\:\d@d.com\,\Phone
\:\3245\,\AddressId\:66,\LocationId\:51},{\DoctorId\:4,\UserId\:0,\FirstName\:\Nitish
\,\MiddleName\:\\,\LastName\:\Rana\,\Qualification\:null,\Description\:null,\Experience
\:null,\Email\:\d@d.com\,\Phone\:\3245\,\AddressId\:67,\LocationId\:52},{\DoctorId
\:5,\UserId\:0,\FirstName\:\Nitish\,\MiddleName\:\\,\LastName\:\Rana\,\Qualification
\:null,\Description\:null,\Experience\:null,\Email\:\d@d.com\,\Phone\:\3245\,\AddressId
\:68,\LocationId\:53},{\DoctorId\:6,\UserId\:0,\FirstName\:\wefwe\,\MiddleName
\:\\,\LastName\:\rthyt\,\Qualification\:\\,\Description\:\\,\Experience\:\\,\Email
\:\w@w.com\,\Phone\:\43256\,\AddressId\:69,\LocationId\:54},{\DoctorId\:7,\UserId
\:0,\FirstName\:\dwefw\,\MiddleName\:\\,\LastName\:\tfhbede\,\Qualification
\:\\,\Description\:\\,\Experience\:\\,\Email\:\w@w.com\,\Phone\:\345\,\AddressId
\:70,\LocationId\:55},{\DoctorId\:8,\UserId\:0,\FirstName\:\ghnsfssw\,\MiddleName
\:\\,\LastName\:\fdvfd\,\Qualification\:\\,\Description\:\\,\Experience\:\\,\Emai
\:\w@w.com\,\Phone\:\3245\,\AddressId\:71,\LocationId\:56},{\DoctorId\:9,\UserId
\:0,\FirstName\:\csdcs\,\MiddleName\:\\,\LastName\:\dfvfgb\,\Qualification
\:\\,\Description\:\\,\Experience\:\\,\Email\:\q@a.com\,\Phone\:\34567\,\AddressId
\:72,\LocationId\:57},{\DoctorId\:10,\UserId\:0,\FirstName\:\regresrg\,\MiddleName
\:\\,\LastName\:\ukyt\,\Qualification\:\\,\Description\:\\,\Experience\:\\,\Email
\:\q@q.com\,\Phone\:\3242567\,\AddressId\:73,\LocationId\:58},{\DoctorId\:11,\UserId
\:0,\FirstName\:\fvger\,\MiddleName\:\\,\LastName\:\ujtyhr\,\Qualification
\:\\,\Description\:\\,\Experience\:\\,\Email\:\d@s.com\,\Phone\:\43567\,\AddressId
\:74,\LocationId\:59},{\DoctorId\:12,\UserId\:0,\FirstName\:\gfere\,\MiddleName
\:\\,\LastName\:\ergfe\,\Qualification\:\\,\Description\:\\,\Experience\:\\,\Email
\:\q@q.com\,\Phone\:\32465\,\AddressId\:75,\LocationId\:60},{\DoctorId\:13,\UserId
\:0,\FirstName\:\erfe\,\MiddleName\:\\,\LastName\:\rtghynu\,\Qualification
\:\\,\Description\:\\,\Experience\:\\,\Email\:\s@q.com\,\Phone\:\23456\,\AddressId
\:76,\LocationId\:61},{\DoctorId\:15,\UserId\:0,\FirstName\:\Nitish\,\MiddleName
\:\\,\LastName\:\Rana\,\Qualification\:null,\Description\:null,\Experience\:null,\Email
\:\d@d.com\,\Phone\:\3245\,\AddressId\:78,\LocationId\:63}]
```

I am getting exception in following line :

```
JSONArray dd = new JSONArray(value);   // value = above json string
```

The exception is :

```
Expected literal value at character 2 of value.
```

Comment: Global search-and-replace all '\\' characters with '"' characters.

Comment: Sorry to disappoint you, but what you have posted is not valid JSON.

Comment: **Parse error on line 2:**
*[    {        \DoctorId\: 3,     *
**--------------^**
*Expecting 'STRING', '}'*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [json.org](http://json.org/) (which must qualify as a credible/official source), JSON `string`s (as used in your JSON `array`, as names and values), *must be quoted using double quotes*:

> A *string* is a sequence of zero or more Unicode characters, wrapped in double quotes, using backslash escapes.

Maybe you or someone else misread this to mean that you should use backslash escapes instead of double quotes?

What it really means is that you must use double quotes (`"`) around your `string`. The backslash character is used only as an escape character *within the quoted string*, should you want to use a double quote, a backslash, a control character or a Unicode character in hexadecimal form, as part of your `string`.

You can read more about the JSON format in the [Ecma 404 standard document](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-404.pdf), although I doubt you'll ever need more than the syntax and examples from json.org.

In any case, your input is invalid according to the JSON format. The exception you get is correct, and expected for this input.

Here's your entire JSON array on human readable and correct form:

```
[
    {
        "DoctorId": 3,
        "UserId": 0,
        "FirstName": "Nitish",
        "MiddleName": "",
        "LastName": "Rana",
        "Qualification": null,
        "Description": null,
        "Experience": null,
        "Email": "d@d.com",
        "Phone": "3245",
        "AddressId": 66,
        "LocationId": 51
    },
    {
        "DoctorId": 4,
        "UserId": 0,
        "FirstName": "Nitish ",
        "MiddleName": "",
        "LastName": "Rana",
        "Qualification": null,
        "Description": null,
        "Experience ": null,
        "Email": "d@d.com",
        "Phone": "3245",
        "AddressId": 67,
        "LocationId": 52
    },
    {
        "DoctorId ": 5,
        "UserId": 0,
        "FirstName": "Nitish",
        "MiddleName": "",
        "LastName": "Rana",
        "Qualification ": null,
        "Description": null,
        "Experience": null,
        "Email": "d@d.com",
        "Phone": "3245",
        "AddressId ": 68,
        "LocationId": 53
    },
    {
        "DoctorId": 6,
        "UserId": 0,
        "FirstName": "wefwe",
        "MiddleName ": "",
        "LastName": "rthyt",
        "Qualification": "",
        "Description": "",
        "Experience": "",
        "Email ": "w@w.com",
        "Phone": "43256",
        "AddressId": 69,
        "LocationId": 54
    },
    {
        "DoctorId": 7,
        "UserId ": 0,
        "FirstName": "dwefw",
        "MiddleName": "",
        "LastName": "tfhbede",
        "Qualification ": "",
        "Description": "",
        "Experience": "",
        "Email": "w@w.com",
        "Phone": "345",
        "AddressId ": 70,
        "LocationId": 55
    },
    {
        "DoctorId": 8,
        "UserId": 0,
        "FirstName": "ghnsfssw",
        "MiddleName ": "",
        "LastName": "fdvfd",
        "Qualification": "",
        "Description": "",
        "Experience": "",
        "Emai ": "w@w.com",
        "Phone": "3245",
        "AddressId": 71,
        "LocationId": 56
    },
    {
        "DoctorId": 9,
        "UserId ": 0,
        "FirstName": "csdcs",
        "MiddleName": "",
        "LastName": "dfvfgb",
        "Qualification ": "",
        "Description": "",
        "Experience": "",
        "Email": "q@a.com",
        "Phone": "34567",
        "AddressId ": 72,
        "LocationId": 57
    },
    {
        "DoctorId": 10,
        "UserId": 0,
        "FirstName": "regresrg",
        "MiddleName ": "",
        "LastName": "ukyt",
        "Qualification": "",
        "Description": "",
        "Experience": "",
        "Email ": "q@q.com",
        "Phone": "3242567",
        "AddressId": 73,
        "LocationId": 58
    },
    {
        "DoctorId": 11,
        "UserId ": 0,
        "FirstName": "fvger",
        "MiddleName": "",
        "LastName": "ujtyhr",
        "Qualification ": "",
        "Description": "",
        "Experience": "",
        "Email": "d@s.com",
        "Phone": "43567",
        "AddressId ": 74,
        "LocationId": 59
    },
    {
        "DoctorId": 12,
        "UserId": 0,
        "FirstName": "gfere",
        "MiddleName ": "",
        "LastName": "ergfe",
        "Qualification": "",
        "Description": "",
        "Experience": "",
        "Email ": "q@q.com",
        "Phone": "32465",
        "AddressId": 75,
        "LocationId": 60
    },
    {
        "DoctorId": 13,
        "UserId ": 0,
        "FirstName": "erfe",
        "MiddleName": "",
        "LastName": "rtghynu",
        "Qualification ": "",
        "Description": "",
        "Experience": "",
        "Email": "s@q.com",
        "Phone": "23456",
        "AddressId ": 76,
        "LocationId": 61
    },
    {
        "DoctorId": 15,
        "UserId": 0,
        "FirstName": "Nitish",
        "MiddleName ": "",
        "LastName": "Rana",
        "Qualification": null,
        "Description": null,
        "Experience": null,
        "Email ": "d@d.com",
        "Phone": "3245",
        "AddressId": 78,
        "LocationId": 63
    }
]
```

As many others have already pointed out, you can easily fix this with a regexp or similar, replacing all `\` characters with the `"` character.

Comment: I am able to get the above Json format. I used the following code : value = value.trim();
value = value.substring(1, value.length()-1);
value = value.replace("\\", "\"");

Comment: I have one class in Java which has excactly same properties. I am trying to set an arraylist of that class with this json. For this I am doing : JsonHelper jsonHelper = new JsonHelper();
ArrayList<Doctor> obj = jsonHelper.fromJSON(new TypeReference<ArrayList<Doctor>>() {}, value); But I am getting null in obj. Can you help me here.

Comment: @Nitish Good stuff. But are you sure you should strip of the `[]` characters around the array? For the second problem, I suggest you ask a new question. Comments are not intended for this.

Comment: That was the issue. There was not [ and ] brackets to represent array. It worked. Thanks :)

Comment: I have accepted your answer but I would be able to award the bounty after 22 hours as per stack overflow.

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON is invalid. I dont know why you have used \ or \\ . Replace those with " or "".

Correct JSON:

```
[
  {
    "DoctorId": 3,
    "UserId": 0,
    "FirstName": "Nitish",
    "MiddleName": "",
    "LastName": "Rana",
    "Qualification": null,
    "Description": null,
    "Experience": null,
    "Email": "d@d.com",
    "Phone": "3245",
    "AddressId": 66,
    "LocationId": 51
  },
  {
    "DoctorId": 4,
    "UserId": 0,
    "FirstName": "Nitish",
    "MiddleName": "",
    "LastName": "Rana",
    "Qualification": null,
    "Description": null,
    "Experience": null,
    "Email": "d@d.com",
    "Phone": "3245",
    "AddressId": 67,
    "LocationId": 52
  },
  {
    "DoctorId": 5,
    "UserId": 0,
    "FirstName": "Nitish",
    "MiddleName": "",
    "LastName": "Rana",
    "Qualification": null,
    "Description": null,
    "Experience": null,
    "Email": "d@d.com",
    "Phone": "3245",
    "AddressId": 68,
    "LocationId": 53
  },
  {
    "DoctorId": 6,
    "UserId": 0,
    "FirstName": "wefwe",
    "MiddleName": "",
    "LastName": "rthyt",
    "Qualification": "",
    "Description": "",
    "Experience": "",
    "Email": "w@w.com",
    "Phone": "43256",
    "AddressId": 69,
    "LocationId": 54
  },
  {
    "DoctorId": 7,
    "UserId": 0,
    "FirstName": "dwefw",
    "MiddleName": "",
    "LastName": "tfhbede",
    "Qualification": "",
    "Description": "",
    "Experience": "",
    "Email": "w@w.com",
    "Phone": "345",
    "AddressId": 70,
    "LocationId": 55
  },
  {
    "DoctorId": 8,
    "UserId": 0,
    "FirstName": "ghnsfssw",
    "MiddleName": "",
    "LastName": "fdvfd",
    "Qualification": "",
    "Description": "",
    "Experience": "",
    "Email": "w@w.com",
    "Phone": "3245",
    "AddressId": 71,
    "LocationId": 56
  },
  {
    "DoctorId": 9,
    "UserId": 0,
    "FirstName": "csdcs",
    "MiddleName": "",
    "LastName": "dfvfgb",
    "Qualification": "",
    "Description": "",
    "Experience": "",
    "Email": "q@a.com",
    "Phone": "34567",
    "AddressId": 72,
    "LocationId": 57
  },
  {
    "DoctorId": 10,
    "UserId": 0,
    "FirstName": "regresrg",
    "MiddleName": "",
    "LastName": "ukyt",
    "Qualification": "",
    "Description": "",
    "Experience": "",
    "Email": "q@q.com",
    "Phone": "3242567",
    "AddressId": 73,
    "LocationId": 58
  },
  {
    "DoctorId": 11,
    "UserId": 0,
    "FirstName": "fvger",
    "MiddleName": "",
    "LastName": "ujtyhr",
    "Qualification": "",
    "Description": "",
    "Experience": "",
    "Email": "d@s.com",
    "Phone": "43567",
    "AddressId": 74,
    "LocationId": 59
  },
  {
    "DoctorId": 12,
    "UserId": 0,
    "FirstName": "gfere",
    "MiddleName": "",
    "LastName": "ergfe",
    "Qualification": "",
    "Description": "",
    "Experience": "",
    "Email": "q@q.com",
    "Phone": "32465",
    "AddressId": 75,
    "LocationId": 60
  },
  {
    "DoctorId": 13,
    "UserId": 0,
    "FirstName": "erfe",
    "MiddleName": "",
    "LastName": "rtghynu",
    "Qualification": "",
    "Description": "",
    "Experience": "",
    "Email": "s@q.com",
    "Phone": "23456",
    "AddressId": 76,
    "LocationId": 61
  },
  {
    "DoctorId": 15,
    "UserId": 0,
    "FirstName": "Nitish",
    "MiddleName": "",
    "LastName": "Rana",
    "Qualification": null,
    "Description": null,
    "Experience": null,
    "Email": "d@d.com",
    "Phone": "3245",
    "AddressId": 78,
    "LocationId": 63
  }
]
```

You can test  whether your json is correct or not.

Sites:

1. http://zaach.github.io/jsonlint/
2. http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/

Answer (score 0):

You JSON looks invalid.

Not sure where your source comes from, but `String`s should be wrapped in double quotes, not back-slashes.

E.g.

```
[
   {
      "DoctorId":3,
      "UserId":0,
...

   }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON is invalid.  The following link provides examples of valid JSON syntax.  [Valid JSON](http://json.org/example)  Note the use of double quotes.  While it is perfectly fine to use single and double quotes interchangeably in JavaScript, single quotes are not valid in JSON.  The fact that you have to escape the double quote characters in Strings should be obvious if you've done any degree of Java programming.